# Writing Crawler for Screen Scraping

Tags: asp.net, screen-scraping, web-crawler

I want to write crawler for screen scraping

What I want is, I want to get price of particular hotel from a website, like here is 
[website](http://globaltrips.lastminute.com/trips/hotellist/list?startIndex=0&checkInDate=2010-12-25&checkOutDate=2010-12-26&hotelMaxReturnPerPage=25&guestCounts=1&ad_dest=LON&guestCodes=ADULT&configId=S72722479&city=London&numRooms=1&serviceTag=LMN0&ad_country=GB&channel=HotelWebUI)

e.g. In the above URL, there is list of hotels and its price. I want to get the price of **`the beaufort`**

Please Advise how to accomplish this.

Comment: why minuus 1, I think I have provide the URL, that's is just for reference and that's not real, its just example.

Comment: @Ross; Thanks for giving good shape to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a HTML parsing library like the [html agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) to parse the html into a more usable model and then navigate the model to find the bits of the HTML you are interested in

Answer (score 0):

download the HTML with a tool like cURL and then use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to select the tags you are interested in. Use Firebug to help you determine the XPath.